# Vue.js - Calling a component's method from Vue instance

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have a created a Vue instance and a global component. How can I call the component's method from my Vue instance?

In my **Vue instance** I did this:

```
methods: {
    handleTabClick: function(tab, event) {
        if (tab.name == 'log') {
            call loadLog function in log component
        }
    }
}
```

Then my **component** is defined as this:

```
Vue.component('jettLog', {
    props: ['shop'],

    data() {
        return {
            log: [],
            logLoading : true
        }
    },

    methods: {
        loadLog: function() {
            console.log("Load");
        },
    },
});
```

How can I call jettLog's function `loadLog` from `handleTabClick()`?

I see different explanations and now I am wondering what's the best way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register a global event bus whixh is an empty vue instance like this:

```
Var EventBus = new Vue();
```

in your vue instance emit an event with `EventVus.$emit()`

```
methods: {
    handleTabClick: function(tab, event) {
        if (tab.name == 'log') {
            EventBus.$emit('log-event')
        }
    }
}
```

`$emit()` takes two arguments:
1: event name
2. event data (optional)

In the created hook of `jettLog` component set up an event listener on the `EventBus` and perform your logic when a paticular event is emitted

```
Vue.component('jettLog', {
    props: ['shop'],

    data() {
        return {
            log: [],
            logLoading : true
        }
    },
    created(){
        var self = this;
        EventBus.$on('log-event', function(eventData){
            self.loadLog();
        });
    },
    methods: {
        loadLog: function() {
            console.log("Load");
        },
    },
});
```

[Check this out for more info](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication)

Comment: Perfect example. Thanks!