# Access Component Method from Parent Method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to find out how can I trigger **click** event on my component element `<img>` from parent method `addPhoto()` so `openUploader()` method will run.

I want to open the File Uploader after pushing a new item to `photos`.

After this: `this.photos.push(newPhoto);`

**Approach Attempt #1:**

I was trying to do this `this.openUploader()`, I know this will not work because method is not there. How can I access the "newPhoto" so I can do something like this: `this.newPhoto.openUploader()`. I tried adding `v-model` on `<img>` but it doesn't work.

**Approach Attempt #2:**

Is Vue have a way for something like this: `<img {{ clickThis() : openTheUploader }} >`

I know how can I do it/click it using vanilla JS/jQuery through traversing on DOM, But I am trying to know if this is possible in Vue JS(I think yes), I just don't know how to do it.

```js
Vue.component('gallery', {
    template: '<div><img v-bind:src="photo" v-on:click="openUploader()" alt="Blank Photo" /><input type="file" ref="photoUploader"></div>',
    props: ['photo'],
    methods: {
        openUploader: function(){
        
           this.$refs.photoUploader.click();
                
        }
    }
});

var photoGallery = new Vue({
    el: '#photoGallery',
    data: {
        photos: [
                   { 
                     'id'   : 1,
                     'photo': 'https://vuejs.org/images/logo.png'
                   }
                ]
    },
    methods: {
        addPhoto: function(){
        
          var newPhoto = [
                          {
                            'id'   : 2,
                            'photo': ''
                          }
                       ];
          this.photos.push(newPhoto);
          // I want to open file uploader of new blank photo here
        
        }
    }
});
```

```css
[type="file"]{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.8/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="photoGallery">

  <gallery v-for="(photo, index) in photos"
           v-bind:key="photo.id"
           v-bind:photo="photo.photo"></gallery>
  <button v-on:click="addPhoto()">
    Add Photo
  </button>

</div>
```

Comment: Check out the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47494953/7814783

Comment: I think like react, we can export components from child and then import it in parent. So if it is possible that specific `methods : { }` "export-able" from methods object? Also If I am wrong, You could use help of state management that will be way better

Answer (score 0):

To call methods on a component, you need to give the component a ref. So in your `<gallery>` tag, put `ref="gallery"`. Then, in your root vue, you can do `this.$refs.gallery.openUploader();`